# Click a html button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to click a html button TWICE to achieve what i need in my project.So i am using a javascript to click the button using click() .But the following script doesnt work for me. Please try this here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>

 <script>document.getElementById('myImage').click();
        document.getElementById('myImage').click();
  </script>


</body>

<script>
function changeImage() {
     alert(100);
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>

</html>
```

I have tried clicking it only once to just see whether i am going in right direction or not,even that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>

<script>
// --> Script code should be before closing body tag
function changeImage() {
     alert(100);
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
document.getElementById('myImage').click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```